# repatation of inserting in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello all,

I am working on a site were a member can send message to all of his/her friends ..

so all of their friends are stored in an array like:

```
$selectfrnds=mysql_query("select sender_id,receiver_id from fk_friends where (sender_id='$id' or receiver_id='$id') and friendtofriend='freq' ");
 $friendis=array();
```

I have imploded the query into a variable and now all their friends are represented:

```
 $frndsall='4','8','2','12','13','14','15','16','18','19','21','23','24','27','35','36','40','43','29','45','44','38','46','22','1'
```

so I just want to ask: How do I insert query that will send a message to all these ids?

I want something like:

```
insert into tablename  (message,id// id of friend ) values ('$message//this is same','$xyz// which is stored into varialbe $frndsall one by one it should insert with all the values')
```

any help please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out php foreach statements (http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) - that should be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Prepared Statements](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) in a [`foreach` loop](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php):

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare(
    "INSERT INTO tablename (message, id) VALUES (:message, :id)");
$stmt->bindParam(':message', $message);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);

foreach ($frndsall as $frndId) {
    $id = $frndId;
    $stmt->execute();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do bulk insert by first preparing a select statement that produces the desired result set to be inserted, then prefixing INSERT into .

Example

```
INSERT INTO tablename (message, id)
SELECT '$message', receiver_id
FROM fk_friends
WHERE (sender_id='$id' or receiver_id='$id') AND friendtofriend='freq'
```

If your database abstraction layer supports prepared statements, something like this is probably the best way to do this query.

```
$db->query($db->prepare('
    INSERT INTO tablename (message, id)
    SELECT ?, receiver_id
    FROM fk_friends
    WHERE (sender_id=? or receiver_id=?) AND friendtofriend=?
'), array($message, $id, $id, 'freq')));
```

Otherwise, if not using prepared statements, be sure to properly escape all data you insert into the query before querying it from the database, using the relevant escaping function for your method of accessing the database.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can do Insert in foreach, but this solution will bad on real project, where user will have more than 3k friends.

Here is a question of database architecture in my mind.
You say:

> member can send message to all of his/her friends

If you want to add possibility to send a message **only** to all, will be better to use separate table like

```
`mass_messages`
id (int 11)
sender_id (int 11)
message (text)
send_date (timestamp)
```

Also you can create another table to store friends who already read your message.
But this way not useful if you try to send message to all except for a few friends.